# R: filter issue - Error in `filter()`: ! Problem while computing `..1 = between(data$column, 400, 1800)`

Tags: r, vector, filter, atomic, rlang

I have a data frame and am looking to get a subset based on conditions related to another column. This seems to work for some variable, but somehow for one particular one, I am getting the following error message:

```
Error in `filter()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = between(Unitranche$Yield, 400, 1800)`.
Caused by error in `Unitranche$Yield`:
! $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

The code is as follows:

```
X = filter(data, X == 1)
Y = filter(data, Y == 1)
Z = filter(data), Z == 1)
```

no problem until here, but then:

```
X = filter(X, between(X$a,400,1500))
Y = filter(Y, between(Y$a,400,1800))
Z = filter(Z, a >= 800)
```

The error pops up for Y, although Y is created/filtered exactly like the X and Z.

Not sure how to replicate this error with sample data; but just in case Y is 278 observations of 5 variables.

Thank you!

Comment: It will be difficult to help without providing an example of Y because there is no error in your code so it may be related to your own data

Comment: hi @Basti, thank you very much. I suspected this... any tips on how to check the data for problems?

Comment: As it stands I do not see, can't you provide an example ? With `dput(Y)` or `dput(head(Y))` ? Have you tried on some subsets of Y to see if the error persist (e.g. Y[1:50,])?

Comment: Hi Basti, apologies for my delayed answer. I realized that the filter applied does not come to effect, i.e. the values in Y$a in are anyway within the range - could that be an error, i.e. the filter cannot find any values to "filter out"?

Comment: It is difficult to answer this question without seeing the data, as I indicated `dput(head(Y))` or `dput(Y)` would be needed